# Finding the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(-2)^n+3^n}{(-2)^{n+1}+3^{n+1}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Find the limit of expression: $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(-2)^n+3^n}{(-2)^{n+1}+3^{n+1}}$$

I've used a joined expression, tried to simplify it. After that, I've got such result:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}1+\frac{3*(-2)^n-2*3^n}{-2(-2)^n+3*3^n}$$
Does anyone have any ideas?
The right answer is $$\frac{1}{3}$$

Comment: (a) figure out what the dominant term in your numerator is; (b) try dividing numerator and denominator by that term.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki thank you for hint)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Divide numerator and denominator by $3^{n+1}$. Then use the fact that $(2/3)^n \to \ 0$.